# last child of a li list using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having a problem taking out the last child of my LI list

here is the code I added #menu-main  li:last { border-right: none; }

http://mothernaturemothernurture.com/  here is the site

Comment: What do you mean by "taking out"? Can't you just remove the HTML? and your link merely leads to an "under construction" page.

Answer (score 4):

> The syntax for selecting last child is **:last-child**, not :last

`#menu-main li:last-child { border-right: none; }`